# How do I insert and return the ID in postgresql?

Tags: .net, postgresql

Pretty straight forward. I guess I could do an insert on conflict do nothing then a select but I like one liners. There may be a conflict because c1 is unique. I'd like to insert then return the id of whatever row has column1 (c1).

```
insert into foo(c1)
    VALUES(@c1, 0)
on conflict (c1) do nothing
RETURNING (select fooid from foo where c1=@c1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the clause `do nothing` is reached the query returns no rows. The only way to return `fooid` in this case is to execute redundant update:

```
insert into foo (c1)
values (@c1)
on conflict (c1) do update set c1 = excluded.c1
returning fooid;
```

Comment: I take it this would be optimized out? (We can assume it should but will it?)

Comment: I don't know, the current interpretation is logical: no action, no results. Your suggestion seems more practical, though.

Comment: Yeah. I could understand if I did `returning fooid` and get no rows. However it's a select statement. Unfortunately it disallows `c1 = c1` which I tried hoping it'd be obvious as a no-op but no I had to use your answer. to the T

Comment: You can use the special record `excluded`, like in the updated answer.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You could use a common table expression to avoid the redundant update:

```
WITH    payload(c1) AS (
    SELECT @c1 -- your parameters here, you might have to CAST() them
), insert_action(c1) AS (
    INSERT INTO foo(c1)
        SELECT c1 FROM payload
    ON CONFLICT (c1) DO NOTHING
    RETURNING c1
)
SELECT  c1
FROM    insert_action
    RIGHT JOIN payload USING(c1);
```